# If a sequence starts from 0 or -1, how do you refer each item?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If a sequence starts numbering from $0$ or even $-1$, how do you refer the first/second item? I would like to know if $(-1)$-th, $0$-th, $1$-st, $2$-nd acceptable?

Comment: Note that $\langle n^2:1\le n\le10\rangle$ and $\langle(n+1)^2:0\le n\le9\rangle$ are the **same sequence**. What is the first term of that sequence?

Comment: "zeroth" and "negative first" are fine. Come to think of it, "first negative", "twenty-second negative" and so on roll off the tongue more nicely.

Comment: What you propose would be acceptable to me.

Comment: @bof If you want to get technical then I will point out that in set theory those two notations _do_ denote different objects.  The first denotes a function with domain $[1,10]$ while the second denotes a function with domain $[0,9]$.

Comment: In this case, my preference is to refer the term by its name. i.e if your sequence is $a_{-1}, a_0, \ldots$, then you refer the "first" term in the sequence as $a_{-1}$. This is shorter and free of ambiguity.

Comment: @TrevorWilson According to Jech's *Set Theory* (1st or should I say 0th edition, p. 16), a sequence is a function whose domain is an ordinal. Thus a $3$-termed sequence $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ is a function on the set $3=\{0,1,2\}$ irrespective of whether you call the items $x,y,z$ or $x_1,x_2,x_3$ or $x_{\pi},x_e,x_i$. (Sadly, set-theorists insist on calling the $(\alpha+1)$-th term the "$\alpha$-th", resulting in such nonsense words as "zeroth" and "omegath".)

Comment: @bof Good point; the first thing you wrote isn't even a sequence because its domain isn't an ordinal.  But still the two things are different as families because their index sets are different.  I'm not sure quite what your parenthetical remark means; what term would you propose in place of $\omega^\text{th}$?

Comment: @bof, in my opinion, a sequence should be any function whose domain is a well-ordered set. Of course, the definitions that are invoked in the usual ZFC-based approach to the foundations has no support for the idea that the domain of a function can be a mathematical structure; the domain of a function can only be that structure's underlying set. So if you're going to do the ZFC approach, then Jech's definition is probably best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call them "term $-1$," "term $0$," "term $1$," and so on.  It may sound slightly awkward, but it avoids the confusion that could be caused by people reading "$1$-st term" as "first term" and assuming that it is the term at the beginning of the sequence.

Comment: I will go with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**. I just corrected the typos. Sorry about that.

Many eons ago, I came up with the following terminology if you're starting at $0$.

0th = nulliceded (preceded by "null" or zero)

1th = uniceded (preceded by 1 term)

2th = biceded  (preceded by 2 terms)

3th = triceded (preceded by 3 terms)

etc.

For example, the uniceded term of $(9,8,7)$ would be $8$ (because it is preceded by exactly one term).

However, when talking to (or writing for) other people, I prefer less creative terminology. For example: "Term $1$ of the sequence equals $8$."

As for beginning at $-1,$ well you can always rename things such that you're starting at $0$. Do you have a specific situation in mind when this would be a bad move?

Comment: If a sequence is beginning at 0, when talk about augmentation, one get a sequence beginning at -1.

Comment: @MaMing, sorry I'm not familiar "augmentation." I'd be interested to learn more, if you can provide a link.

Comment: @MaMing, also I corrected all the typos in the terminology.